# how to get a dynamic customer attribute option from eav_atrribute_option _value table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, eav-attributes

how to get a dynamic attribute `options` from eav_atrribute_option _value table in magento 2

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/Model/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
  <?php
namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Model\Plugin\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
     public function __construct(\Bootsgrid\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

 $attributeCollection = $this->helper->getUserDefinedAttribures();

    if ($attributeCollection->getSize() > 0) 
    {
         foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute)

       {
        if ($this->helper->isAttribureForCheckoutRegister($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
        {
        $frontEndLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel($this->helper->getStoreId());
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $getAttributeCodeFunction = "get" .  str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $attribute->getAttributeCode())));
        $fieldRequiredClass = ($attribute->getIsRequired()) ? 'true' : '' ;
        $fieldFrontendClass = ($attribute->getFrontendClass()) ? $attribute->getFrontendClass() : '';
        $fieldInput =$attribute->getFrontendInput();
        if($fieldInput == 'text')
        {
            $fieldInputType = 'input';
            $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'date') {
           $fieldInputType = 'date'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'select') {
           $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'select';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'multiselect') {
           $fieldInputType = 'multiselect'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'boolean') {
           $fieldInputType = 'boolean'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
         elseif ($fieldInput == 'textarea') {
           $fieldInputType = 'textarea'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';

        }
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$attributeCode] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/'.$fieldAbstract.'',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/'.$fieldInputType.'',
                'id' => $attributeCode
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.'.$attributeCode.'',
            'label' => $frontEndLabel,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' =>[$fieldFrontendClass , 'required-entry' => $fieldRequiredClass],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
             'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Please select a value ',
                ],

 [
                    'value' => '1',
                    'label' => 'Silver level ',
                ],
            ],  
            'id' => $attributeCode
        ];

        }
       }
     }
     return $jsLayout;  
    }
}
```

image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the example of fetching options of customer attribute

> Object Manager Approach

```
/**
 * Get attribute info by attribute code and entity type
 */
$attributeCode = 'gender';
$entityType = 'customer';

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$attributeInfo = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::class)
                               ->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);


/**
 * Get all options name and value of the attribute
 */
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();

var_dump($attributeOptionAll->getData());
```

> Block Approach

if you want to do it through block then add this block in your module

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;

class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute
     */
    protected $_entityAttribute;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection
     */
    protected $_entityAttributeCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection
     */
    protected $_entityAttributeOptionCollection;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute $entityAttribute
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection $eavEntityAttributeCollection 
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection $entityAttributeOptionCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute $entityAttribute,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Collection $entityAttributeCollection, 
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection $entityAttributeOptionCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_entityAttribute = $entityAttribute;
        $this->_entityAttributeCollection = $entityAttributeCollection; 
        $this->_entityAttributeOptionCollection = $entityAttributeOptionCollection;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute info by attribute code and entity type
     *
     * @param mixed $entityType can be integer, string, or instance of class Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Type
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute
     */
    public function getAttributeInfo($entityType, $attributeCode)
    {
        return $this->_entityAttribute->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);
    }

    /**
     * Get all options name and value of the attribute
     *
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributeOptionAll($attributeId)
    {
        return $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                    ->setStoreFilter()
                    ->load();
    }

    /**
     * Get particular option's name and value of the attribute
     *
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @param int $optionId
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributeOptionById($attributeId, $optionId)
    {
        return $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                    ->setIdFilter($optionId)
                    ->setStoreFilter()
                    ->load();
    }

    /**
     * Get the first option's name and value of the attribute
     *
     * @param int $attributeId
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection
     */
    public function getAttributeFirstOption($attributeId)
    {
        return $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                    ->load()
                    ->getFirstItem();
    } 
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: how to get a customer attribute option

Comment: ok I updated my answer. you actually edited the question and add `customer` in it. I also share the block approach if you want. Right now I share the approach which attribute through object manager

Comment: thank you @Muhammad hasham i will tried and update you

Comment: its works what i m expect thank you

Comment: Glad it helps +1 on your question for appreciation.

Comment: how to get a some content alone https://prnt.sc/ockdt1

Comment: i have used this `var_dump($attributeOptionAll->getData('value'));`

Comment: Though I didn't test this, but it should be like this foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $v) { echo $v['option_id']; echo $v['value']; }

Comment: k i will try this

Comment: its works fine in block  file but i want to used directly into layoutprocessor.php file  its reflects a error